# how to call api in background React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `function` that is called every 2 min to send my current location to the `API`, but does not work when the app is in the `background`, how would it continue to call my method even in the `background`?

```
pls = () => {
        if(!myVar){
            this._sendLocation()
            myVar = setInterval(this._sendLocation, time)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a lot of time on this question and the only realistic option I've found that will work on both Android and iOS is [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-geolocation)

It **isn't a perfect** solution.  It is free to use on iOS, but quite expensive on Android (300?), although it comes with some nifty Android testing tools.

An option is to use the package for iOS and Jitender's headless solution on Android.